Site on render.com "suspended due to a high volume of service-initiated traffic" without warning
For the last few months, I've been running an app using render.com. I noticed the app was having issues to today I logged in to find this warning:
Your service has been suspended due to a high volume of service-initiated traffic.
Upgrade to a paid instance to restore your service.

There's a little more information about this error at https://docs.render.com/free#service-initiated-traffic-threshold but I still have questions. Does anyone know what the limits are here? Render doesn't give any information. I was making 5-10 calls to an API per minute, and I'm guessing that was the issue. What's strange is that the service ran for multiple months without any problem, and then this suspension came without warning.

even I was facing the issue, actually the amount of data sent during request response is also considered, so even though API calls are low if data transferred is high might cause render to suspend service.
read this - https://community.render.com/t/how-much-api-calls-for-free-tier/22873
